# Smarty get current template filename / line

Tags: php, smarty

I would like to get the current template file / line from a plugin function in smarty for profiling/debugging purposes.

Is it possible to do by using the passed $smarty object ?

something like this

```
function __smarty_add_javascript($params, $smarty){
        Profiler::console('Add javascript @[FILE]#[LINE]');
    Controller_Template_Base::getInstance()->javascripts[] = array_pop($params);
}
```

I am able to access the filename by using `$smarty->source->filepath` however i couldnt find any line information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can access the original template's properties from a plugin in runtime. But you can use the http://php.net/debug_backtrace function to access the caller place's informations. (Of course this information will be based on the compiled file, not the original. But It is better than nothing.)

Comment: Yes, now I understand that would be virtually impossible due to the file being compiled. it would have to set $smarty->current_line before executing any function.. I guess ill just ommit the line info.